# How to interchange screen in tkinter gui with multiple script files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have made two separate GUI screens, one as `login.py` and `user_intern.py` and in `user_intern.py` I have a button called `login_button`, so when I click login the `login.py` which contains GUI for login screen should execute and the `user_intern.py` should close automatically and I didn't used class (OOP) here, I have written code fully with functions only so hereby I attached the codes and screenshots of screens.

**`User_intern.py`**

[user_intern.py_pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0xvA.png)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import os
import pickle
import mysql.connector  as sql
from tkinter import messagebox


def login1():
    host = host_entry.get()
    port = port_entry.get()
    username = username_entry.get()
    password = password_entry.get()
    database="cars"

    spec=sql.connect(host=host,user=username,password=password,port=port)
    if spec.is_connected():
        messagebox.showinfo("Connected","Database connected Sucessfully")
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Exists", "Database is already connected")
    spec.close()


root = Tk()
root.geometry("1067x600")
root.configure(background="black")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title("School Diaries")

#background image
bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="files\Sublime Light1.jpg")
lbl_bg = Label(root,image=bg)
lbl_bg.place(x=0,y=0,relwidth=1,relheight=1)

#Labels
host_label = Label(root, text="Host Name ", bg="white", fg="#4f4e4d",font=("yu gothic ui", 12, "bold"))
host_label.place(x=675, y=115)
host_entry = Entry(root, highlightthickness=0, relief=FLAT, bg="white", fg="#6b6a69",font=("yu gothic ui semibold", 12))
#host_entry.insert(0, "localhost")
host_entry.place(x=687, y=139, width=145)

port_label = Label(root, text="Port ", bg="white", fg="#4f4e4d",font=("yu gothic ui", 13, "bold"))
port_label.place(x=675, y=190)
port_entry = Entry(root, highlightthickness=0, relief=FLAT, bg="white", fg="#6b6a69",font=("yu gothic ui semibold", 12))
#port_entry.insert(0, "3307")
port_entry.place(x=690, y=213, width=145)

username_label = Label(root, text="Username ", bg="white", fg="#4f4e4d",font=("yu gothic ui", 13, "bold"))
username_label.place(x=675, y=265)
username_entry = Entry(root, highlightthickness=0, relief=FLAT, bg="white", fg="#6b6a69",font=("yu gothic ui semibold", 12))
#username_entry.insert(0, "root")
username_entry.place(x=687, y=287, width=145)

password_label = Label(root, text="Password ", bg="white", fg="#4f4e4d",font=("yu gothic ui", 13, "bold"))
password_label.place(x=675, y=338)
password_entry = Entry(root, highlightthickness=0, relief=FLAT, bg="white", fg="#6b6a69",font=("yu gothic ui semibold", 12))
#password_entry.insert(0, "root")
password_entry.place(x=687, y=361, width=145)

#buttons
submit = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='Pics\submit.png')
submit_button = Button(root, image=submit,font=("yu gothic ui", 13, "bold"), relief=FLAT, activebackground="white",borderwidth=0, background="white", cursor="hand2",command=login1)
submit_button.place(x=655, y=440)

login = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='Pics\login.png')
login_button = Button(root, image=login,font=("yu gothic ui", 13, "bold"), relief=FLAT, activebackground="white",borderwidth=0, background="white", cursor="hand2")
login_button.place(x=785, y=442)

root.mainloop()
```

**`login.py`**

[login.py_pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1UWi.png)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import os
import pickle
import mysql.connector  as sql
from tkinter import messagebox


def login():
    #host = user_inter.host_entry.get()
    #port = user_inter.port_entry.get()
    username = username_entry.get()
    password = password_entry.get()

    spec=sql.connect(host=host,user=username,password=password,port=port)
    if spec.is_connected():
        messagebox.showinfo("Connected","Database connected Sucessfully")
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Exists", "Failed")

    mycur=spec.cursor()
    mycur.execute()


root = Tk()
root.geometry("1067x600")
root.configure(background="black")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title("School Diaries")

#background
bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="files\login.jpg")
lbl_bg = Label(root,image=bg)
lbl_bg.place(x=0,y=0,relwidth=1,relheight=1)

#Labels
login_lbl = Label(root, text="Login", bg="white", fg="#4f4e4d",font=("San Francisco", 45))
login_lbl.place(x=757,y=120)

username_label = Label(root, text="Username ", bg="white", fg="#4f4e4d",font=("yu gothic ui", 13, "bold"))
username_label.place(x=675, y=190)
username_entry = Entry(root, highlightthickness=0, relief=FLAT, bg="white", fg="#6b6a69",font=("yu gothic ui semibold", 12))
#username_entry.insert(0, "root")
username_entry.place(x=695, y=215, width=190)

password_label = Label(root, text="Password ", bg="white", fg="#4f4e4d",font=("yu gothic ui", 13, "bold"))
password_label.place(x=675, y=280)
password_entry = Entry(root, highlightthickness=0, relief=FLAT, bg="white", fg="#6b6a69",font=("yu gothic ui semibold", 12))
#password_entry.insert(0, "root")
password_entry.place(x=692, y=305, width=190)

login = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='Pics\login.png')
login_button = Button(root, image=login,font=("yu gothic ui", 13, "bold"), relief=FLAT, activebackground="white",borderwidth=0, background="white", cursor="hand2")
login_button.place(x=770, y=390)

root.mainloop()
```

You can do any edits in code to get the output.

Comment: You need to provide a simplified [mre] that illustrates the problem, not your whole program with all kinds of unrelated stuff in it.

Comment: In fact, writing a [example] may help you narrow things down and solve the problem. As far as I can see, nowhere do you make an attempt to run a command when `login_button` is pressed. You don't pass the `command` option and you don't call `login_button.bind()`. We aren't just going to write your code for you; you have to show that you've made an honest attempt at solving the problem before you come ask us for help. See [ask] and the [help] for more information.